# Is it possible to display different link pages by Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am developing by flutter for web.

It is currently possible to go from the main page to the profile page, but is it possible to keep those URLs separate?
For example:

> Main page : https:// testapp.com/home

> Profile page: https:// testapp.com/profile

When I execute the `profilePage()` function, `Navigator.push` will take me to the Profile page.

```
   void profilePage() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => showProfile(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`showProfile` is executed with a different dart file to complete the page navigation.

```
 class showProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: const Center(
            child: Text("Test App",
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          )),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, the Main page and Profile page have the same URL (https:// testapp.com/#/).
Therefore, even if the user types testapp.com/profile, they cannot jump to the profile page.
My purpose is to go to a different URL in Navigator.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This web site helped my issue.

https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-web-navigating-urls-using-named-routes-307e1b1e2050

Solution;

Write the following code in the main function.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
    },
    title: "test",
    home: (),
  ));
}
```

Declare the following in the widget whose URL you want to be "domain.com/ profile" (To be exact, "domain.com/#/profile").

```
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
    static const String route = '/profile';
}
```

And finally, call this.

```
onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProfilePage.route);
},
```

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 0):

Add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro) dependancy/plugin.

Now, Create a file with name routing.dart and add this code:-

```
    class FluroRouting {
      static final router = FluroRouter();
      static Handler _profileHandler = Handler(
          handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
              Profile());
      static Handler _homeHandler = Handler(
          handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
              HomePage());
      static void setupRouter() {
        router.define('/home', handler: _homeHandler,);
        router.define('/profile', handler: _profileHandler,);
router.notFoundHandler = Handler(
        handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>HomePage()
    );
      }
      static void navigateToPage({String routeName,BuildContext context}) {
        router.navigateTo(context, routeName, transition: TransitionType.none);
      }
      static void pushAndClearStackToPage({String routeName,BuildContext context}) {
        router.navigateTo(context, routeName, clearStack: true,transition: TransitionType.none);
      }
    }
```

Now you need to initialize and setup these routes so modify your void main as:-

```
void main()async {
  FluroRouting.setupRouter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'My Website',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/home',
      onGenerateRoute: FluroRouting.router.generator,
    );
  }
}
```

And whenever you need to navigate then simply use the below code:-

```
FluroRouting.navigateToPage(routeName:"/profile",context:context);
```